# Microsoft Edge how to enable time traveling debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, microsoft-edge, time-travel

Is there a way to enable the time travel debug features as shown in [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/Marron/Time-Travel-Debugging-for-JavaScriptHTML)? I don't see a step backward button in my Edge, does it need to be enabled first somehow? Is it even available to the public at the moment or the video was more of a proof of concept and it's not gonna be in the browser any time soon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not available yet. We don't have any release date up to now. Andy has been demonstrating it to show the kind of stuff we're working on. And yes this feature is awesome but we've got to wait for it. ;)

Comment: I guess it's not going to happen now? Unless you plan to work on a version for Blink/V8...